# Is routing slip really deprecated?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I just tried to make a route with a routing slip:

```
from("direct:start").routingSlip("myHeader")
```

Just like it says in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/routing-slip.html).  However, routingSlip(String) is deprecated.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [javadocs](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#routingSlip%28java.lang.String%29) for the method that you're calling. It explains that it's deprecated and which method you should be using instead.

> Deprecated. prefer to use [routingSlip(org.apache.camel.Expression)](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/model/ProcessorDefinition.html#routingSlip%28org.apache.camel.Expression%29) instead